# Do I need to purchase additional Client access Licenses for TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, licensing, msdn

We are considering purchasing TFS 2010, and don't have an MSDN Subscription as of now. Consider two scenarios

1 - Purchasing MSDN Subscription.
2 - Purchasing TFS outside MSDN

In both scenarios, how many number of CALs are available, and how many we need to purchase more? What will be the cost involved? Assume that we need to support around 100 developers.

Comment: Voting to close: Questions about licensing are off-topic on Stackoverflow ( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/18192 )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 5):

If you purchase a MSDN subscription  (specifically Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN, Visual Studio Premium with MSDN, Visual Studio Professional with MSDN, and Visual Studio Test Professional with MSDN), you'll get a TFS server license that has a EULA exception allowing up to 5 users without CALs. After that, CALs are $500 each.

If you purchase the retail version of TFS server, you'll get five CALs.

The primary difference is that CALs can be used to access multiple TFS instances. A EULA exception cannot.

MSDN pricing:

http://devmatter.blogspot.com/2010/01/visual-studio-and-tfs-2010-pricing.html

Comment: Each additional CAL costs 500$? Also, does Visual Studio 2008/2010 purchases comes with a CAL, or I've to buy CALs additionally?

Comment: Yes, each additional CAL costs $500.  If you purchase VS 2010, it does not come with a CAL unless you buy  the MSDN subscription along with it.  So, you could buy VS 2010 for $799 + $500 for a TFS CAL - or - buy VS 2010 w/MSDN for $1199.  Saving you $100 per user.

In your case though (100 users), you should contact a volume license dealer b/c you'll get some discount off retail.

Comment: Definitely contact your license rep from MS.  There are lots of deals going on all the time.

Comment: For Visual Studio Pro 2012 with MSDN there seems to be no TFS CAL included. Only Test professional, premium and ultimate get a TFS CAL. So MSDN is basically worthless in 2012+.

Comment: An update for people reading this, TFS & TFS CAL is included in all VS with MSDN subscriptions.
See: http://www.visualstudio.com/products/msdn-subscriptions-vs

Answer (score 0):

Thats not right. You got only ONE CAL using MSDN subscription (But 5 CALs using TFS retail version).

see:
"Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and MSDN Licensing"

Bruno

Comment: You'll notice my answer was referring to VS2010, not 2012.  So, my answer is correct in the context of the question.